# Why does Comfrey Break Down Easily?

Tags: decomposition

comfrey (*Symphytum officinale*) is a well known plant to organic growers. One of its features is that the leaves break down very quickly, either in water or in a container closed from UV light. There must be some chemical explanation for this, can you explain to me what that is ?

Thanks Erin

Comment: Is this observation anecdotal or can you provide a reliable reference? How is this different from other plants? Many leaves wilt quickly, there is nothing necessarily singular about comfrey. And, what is the link to chemistry. Do you think there might be some biochemical feature as opposed to simple dehydration? What do you use as a measure of "breaking down"?

Comment: Welcome to chemistry SE. Questions are expected to be related to chemistry, and it is not clear yours is. You may have difficulty finding a botanist with expertise on comfrey at this site, particularly if, as you write, there is not much information on it. What do you mean by "the chemical structure is well known"? Chemical structure of what exactly?

Comment: https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Comfrey#section=2D-Structure

Comment: This is a chemical question - link above !

Comment: Ok, but you may want to distinguish between comfrey the plant and a particular compound ([7-[(E)-2-methylbut-2-enoyl]oxy-4-oxido-5,6,7,8-tetrahydro-3H-pyrrolizin-4-ium-1-yl]methyl 2-hydroxy-2-(1-hydroxyethyl)-3-methylbutanoate) within the plant, which the link you provided refers to. Why would breakdown of the plant be related to this particular compound?

Comment: This is interesting information, but you need to provide further background that clarifies what you are asking- it's like claiming that caffeine is somehow linked to the breakdown of leaves in the coffee plant in water. Why should it?

Comment: I don't know that's why I am asking here, but am moving on because I am getting no where here.

Comment: You are more likely to make progress by contacting the local agricultural outreach department of a state university. For instance, look at the link that @M.Farooq provided, it's full of information that might explain physicochemically why the plant degrades rapidly, including the fact that it's rich in nutrients (N, minerals), which is why it was considered a promising forage plant. Also, it can be used to isolate allantoin, which has cosmetic applications. But it also has teratogenic (toxic) compounds which is why it is not highly recommended for human or animal consumption.

Answer (score 1):

Erin, the main the problem with the question is apparently this part "*One of its features is that the leaves break down very quickly, either in water or in a container closed from UV light*." You also mention the compound *comfrey* and wonder if this is responsible for a quick decomposition? I don't think so.

The key question is that Comfrey plant decomposes quickly, as you observed, but compared to which plants? I don't think it is unique that it decomposes rather quickly in soil, water etc. Don't other plants like spinach leaves decompose or spoil quickly? You can easily eliminate UV because UV cannot penetrate compost. It must be bacterial / fungal action.

You can use Google Scholar to fetch scientific papers only and one of the scientific papers says *"Comfrey on a dry weight basis is very high in ash, averaging 18 percent at Rosemount and ranging from 13 to 42 percent in other parts of the world (4). A partial
elemental composition of comfrey forage is reported in Table 4. The forage is particularly high in potassium and is higher than many other forage crops in calcium,
phosphorus, iron, and copper. Carbon, hydrogen, oxygen, nitrogen, and sulfur are the major non-mineral elements. The combined high nitrogen and high mineral concentrations make comfrey forage an unusually good material for composting, mulching, and organic fertilization of crops"*

From Comfrey: A Controversial Crop https://conservancy.umn.edu/handle/11299/141442

The high nitrogen content could be reason for its quick decomposition by bacteria or fungi, however it is hard to assign a single compound "comfrey" as being responsible for it.

Comment: Thanks M.Farooq for having a look around the question but it is a long way from being resolved. If you take 'wood' for instance, I understand that it's C-C bond give it certain properties, and some shells have a structure with silicon bonds which have similarities. Now consider the bonding in the 'comfrey' leaf. If you are a gardener the speed with which comfrey breaks down compared to any other plant is notable. You mention nitrogen bonds, I'd be inclined to concur but I haven't really got any further. Are these bonds particularly weak ?

Comment: One can only wish if living things were that simple. Just an example: No one still knows the total analysis of human blood. There are thousands and thousands of molecules in the blood. There is a whole field in chemistry called "-omics" in which people try to know each an every component using million dollar instruments. In the same way, no one Earth knows what is the total composition of a leaf, that too of comfrey which is perhaps not that important to chemists. contd....

Comment: contd...Therefore it is invalid to consider the "bonding" in a comfrey leaf. As you know composting is an action of bacteria or fungi. If they did not exist, comfrey leaf could take ages to break down. Some things decompose faster because bacteria and fungi and consume it faster, and some take a while. Wood has tons of compounds as well, the story does not end knowing that there in C-C bonds, it is perhaps not even the beginning. It is just that wood is not that nutritious for bacteria and fungi, otherwise there would be no wood-houses. All of them would have composted by now.

Comment: No offense to you M.Farooq you did your best.  But I think generally the moderators on this site need to take the rod out of their asses. They are complicating this question because of their anal retentiveness, get a life - time wasters.